# Equivalence between two orthonormal bases in a Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics, orthonormal, change-of-basis

I want to prove that if I have two orthonormal basis in a Hilbert space labeled by $$ | \theta \rangle, | E \rangle, $$
then the following relationship should hold:
$$ |E\rangle = \left( \frac{dE}{d\theta} \right)^{-1/2} |\theta \rangle ,$$
where $$E = 4 \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2} $$ are both eigenvalues of a Hamiltonian with respective eigenvalues.

I have an idea of how to prove it, but it's definitely not a formal proof. My idea was to impose the equivalence:
$$\delta(\theta - \theta') = \delta (E-E') = \langle \theta | \theta' \rangle = \langle E | E' \rangle .$$

To semplify the notation, let's shift everything:
$$E-E' \rightarrow E  \quad \quad \quad \theta - \theta' \rightarrow \theta .$$
Then, by the definition of the dirac delta of a function:
$$\delta (E(\theta)) = \sum_i \frac{\delta(\theta - \theta_i)}{|E'(\theta_i)|} = \delta (\theta).$$

Now, I don't know how to formally proceed to split this derivative term into its two square roots in order to get the equivalence on top.

Answer (score 1):

For the map to be bijective (monotonic), you might as well choose $E\in [0,2], ~~\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$. You garbled your equivalence, then.

Note
$E= 2(1-\cos\theta), \leadsto dE/d\theta= 2\sin\theta$.

You wish to see how the normalizations of the two labels can be  harmonized,
$$
 |E\rangle = c |\theta \rangle ,\\
 \langle E | E' \rangle =\delta (E-E')=c~c'\langle \theta | \theta' \rangle = c'~c~\delta(\theta - \theta')  , 
$$
as you have changed the integration measure of the variable labels of your states.

Indeed, for your variables,
$$\delta (E(\theta)-E(\theta')) =  \frac{\delta(\theta - \theta')}{|dE(\theta)/d\theta|} = c^2 \delta(\theta - \theta'),\\
\leadsto c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{dE/d\theta}} .$$